# How to do JSON field validation

Tags: json, validation

I have a Restful web service that gets the content from JSON schema. Now I want to validate the fields of this JSON schema. My web service registers the user, hence I have fields like first_name, last_name, email, phone, etc. My validation should be like first_name and last_name should be at least 2 characters long and at most 20 characters long, email should be valid, phone should be 10 digit long, etc. How to do these kinds of validation?

I read a doc and there they mentioned to do the following to the string fields but it isn't working and I could't find anything to pattern match or numbers. Any help will be appreciated.

```
"first_name": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 2,
        "maxLength": 20
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be use the [Voluptous](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous) library.

> Voluptuous, despite the name, is a Python data validation library. It is primarily intended for validating data coming into Python as JSON, YAML, etc.